# Nested recyclerview performance issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made a calendar using recyclerviews, but when i add notes it starts lagging very hard (even crashing)[image: screenshot of activity]
the calendar is made up out of a main recyclerview to scroll left/right and every day has an individual recyclerview to display the notes. I can add as many notes to an individual day as i want without it lagging but when i add a note to like 10-15 separate days its starts lagging real bad. Functionally it works exactly as i want so it would be great if i don't have to change it to much to make it not lag.

I tried using a viewpool but that barely does anything and it makes the view unstable (notes not loading, stuff like that)

```
class CalendarAdapter(val items: MutableList<CalendarClass>,val dayListener: OnDayClickListener, val notificationlistener: CalendarDayAdapter.OnButtonClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarAdapter.CalendarPickerViewHolder>() {

private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()
private val viewPool2 = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

inner class CalendarPickerViewHolder(currentItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(currentItemView), View.OnClickListener {
    init {
        for(i in 0..6) {
            currentItemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week1).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this)
            currentItemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week2).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this)
            currentItemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week3).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this)
            currentItemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week4).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this)
            currentItemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week5).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    }
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        val position: Int = bindingAdapterPosition
        val currentTodoItem = items[position]
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            dayListener.onDayClick(p0, currentTodoItem.month, currentTodoItem.year)
        }
    }
}

// this creates the needed ViewHolder class that links our layout XML to our viewHolder
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendarPickerViewHolder {
    // don't forget to set attachToRoot to false, otherwise it will crash!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.calender_month, parent, false)
    val viewHolder = CalendarPickerViewHolder(view)
    //Log.e("createmonth","createmonth")
    return viewHolder
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendarPickerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Log.e("reusemonth","reusemonth")
    val currentTodoItem = items[position]
    currentTodoItem.name

    holder.itemView.apply {
        if(currentTodoItem.name.trim().isNotEmpty()) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.monthYearText).text = currentTodoItem.name
        }
        val week1 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week1)
        val week2 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week2)
        val week3 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week3)
        val week4 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week4)
        val week5 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.week5)
        week1.getChildAt(0)

        class CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context: Context) :
            GridLayoutManager(context, 7) {
            override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }
        //week1.layoutManager = CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context)
        //week2.layoutManager = CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context)
        //week3.layoutManager = CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context)
        //week4.layoutManager = CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context)
        //week5.layoutManager = CustomHorizontalLinearLayout(context)
        //viewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(holder.itemViewType,200)
        //viewPool2.setMaxRecycledViews(holder.itemViewType,200)
        //week1.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
        //week2.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
        //week3.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
        //week4.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
        //week5.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)


        fun getMonthLength(year:Int,month:Int): Int {
            if(year % 4 == 0 && month == 2){
                return 29
            }
            when (month) {
                1 -> return 31
                2 -> return 28
                3 -> return 31
                4 -> return 30
                5 -> return 31
                6 -> return 30
                7 -> return 31
                8 -> return 31
                9 -> return 30
                10 -> return 31
                11 -> return 30
                12 -> return 31

                else -> { // Note the block
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }
        var index = 0
        fun equalDate(year:Int,month:Int,day:Int): MutableList<NotificationData> {
            for(i in 0 until currentTodoItem.notificationdata.size){
                if (currentTodoItem.notificationdata[i].year == year && currentTodoItem.notificationdata[i].month == month && currentTodoItem.notificationdata[i].day == day)
                {
                    index = i
                    return currentTodoItem.notificationdata[i].data
                }
            }
            return mutableListOf(NotificationData("",WHITE,"","",Time_hour_minutes(0,0)))
        }

        var week = 1
        val dayOfLastMonthDate = LocalDate.of(currentTodoItem.year, currentTodoItem.month, 1).dayOfWeek.value
        val monthLength = getMonthLength(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month)
        var previousMonthLength: Int
        if(currentTodoItem.month>1){
            previousMonthLength = getMonthLength(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month-1)
        }
        else{
             previousMonthLength = getMonthLength(currentTodoItem.year-1,12)
        }

        fun createAdapterWeek1(weeks : LinearLayout) {
            //var listWeek: MutableList<CalendarMonthClass> = mutableListOf()
            //last days of previous months
            for (i in 1 until dayOfLastMonthDate){
                if(currentTodoItem.month>1){
                    //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month-1,previousMonthLength-dayOfDate+i+1), index, previousMonthLength-dayOfDate+i+1,currentTodoItem.month-1,currentTodoItem.year))
                    weeks.getChildAt(i-1).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1).toString()
                    val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month-1,previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1),previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1,currentTodoItem.month-1,currentTodoItem.year,notificationlistener, index)
                    val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i-1).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                    dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                    dayView.adapter = adapter
                }
                else{
                    //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year-1,12,previousMonthLength-dayOfDate+i+1), index, previousMonthLength-dayOfDate+i+1,12,currentTodoItem.year-1))
                    weeks.getChildAt(i-1).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1).toString()
                    val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year-1,12,previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1),previousMonthLength-dayOfLastMonthDate+i+1,12,currentTodoItem.year-1,notificationlistener, index)
                    val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i-1).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                    dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                    dayView.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            for (i in 0..7-dayOfLastMonthDate) {
                //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,week), index, week,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year))
                weeks.getChildAt(i+dayOfLastMonthDate-1).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (week).toString()
                val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,week),week,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year,notificationlistener, index)
                val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i+dayOfLastMonthDate-1).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                dayView.adapter = adapter

                if(week>=monthLength){
                    for (j in 0..i){
                        //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,0), index, 0,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year))
                        weeks.getChildAt(i+dayOfLastMonthDate-1).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (0).toString()
                        val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,0),0,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year,notificationlistener, index)
                        val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i+dayOfLastMonthDate-1).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                        dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                        //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                        dayView.adapter = adapter
                    }
                    break
                }
                else{
                    week++
                }
            }
            //return CalendarMonthAdapter(listWeek, dayListener,notificationlistener,viewPool)
        }
        fun createAdapter(weeks : LinearLayout) {
            //var listWeek: MutableList<CalendarMonthClass> = mutableListOf()
            for (i in 0..6) {
                //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,week), index, week,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year))
                weeks.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (week).toString()
                val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month,week),week,currentTodoItem.month,currentTodoItem.year,notificationlistener, index)
                val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                dayView.adapter = adapter

                if(week>=monthLength){
                    for (j in 1..6-i){
                        if(currentTodoItem.month < 12){
                            //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month+1,j), index, j,currentTodoItem.month+1,currentTodoItem.year))
                            weeks.getChildAt(i+j).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (j).toString()
                            val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year,currentTodoItem.month+1,j),j,currentTodoItem.month+1,currentTodoItem.year,notificationlistener, index)
                            val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i+j).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                            dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                            //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                            dayView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                        else{
                            //listWeek.add(CalendarMonthClass(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year+1,1,j), index, j,1,currentTodoItem.year+1))
                            weeks.getChildAt(i+j).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = (j).toString()
                            val adapter = CalendarDayAdapter(equalDate(currentTodoItem.year+1,1,j),j,1,currentTodoItem.year+1,notificationlistener, index)
                            val dayView = weeks.getChildAt(i+j).findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationView)
                            dayView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                            //dayView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool2)
                            dayView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                    }
                    break
                }
                else{
                    week++
                }
            }
            //return CalendarMonthAdapter(listWeek, dayListener,notificationlistener,viewPool)
        }
        createAdapterWeek1(week1)
        createAdapter(week2)
        createAdapter(week3)
        createAdapter(week4)
        createAdapter(week5)
    }
}
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

interface OnDayClickListener{
    fun onDayClick(view: View?, month: Int, year: Int)
}
}
```

↑ main adapter

```
class CalendarDayAdapter(val items: MutableList<NotificationData>,val day: Int,val month: Int,val year: Int, val listener: OnButtonClickListener, val datePosition: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarDayAdapter.CalendarPickerViewHolder>() {

inner class CalendarPickerViewHolder(currentItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(currentItemView), View.OnClickListener{
    init {
        currentItemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.notification).setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        val position : Int = bindingAdapterPosition
        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            listener.onButtonClick(day,month,year,p0, position, datePosition)
        }
    }
}

// this creates the needed ViewHolder class that links our layout XML to our viewHolder
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendarPickerViewHolder {
    // don't forget to set attachToRoot to false, otherwise it will crash!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.notification, parent, false)
    //Log.e("create","create")
    return CalendarPickerViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendarPickerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Log.e("reuseday","reuseday")
    val currentTodoItem = items[position]

    holder.itemView.apply {
        val notification = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.notification)
        if (currentTodoItem.title.isNotBlank()) {
            notification.text = currentTodoItem.title
            notification.background.setTint(currentTodoItem.color)
        }
        else {
            notification.visibility = INVISIBLE
        }
    }
}
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

interface OnButtonClickListener{
    fun onButtonClick(day :Int,month :Int,year :Int, view : View?, position : Int, datePosition : Int)
}
}
```

↑ adapter for individual days

Comment: We have no idea what's causing the problem without code.  We'd likely need your adapters and any code that would alter any of those adapters

Comment: ps: sorry for the messy code, i was gonna clean it up when it works properly

Comment: Well one thing is that you should never be calling findViewById in onBindViewHolder.  The entire point of the ViewHolder class is to save those things and avoid it in the future.  I also see a few bugs-  if you set something in a block of a view holder, you must do it in ALL the logical branches, or they won't be set right upon recycling.

Comment: Also your onBindViewHolder for the outer adapter is badly designed.  You should NOT be setting up new adapters for the nested recyclers for each bind call.  That's killing your perf.  They should be created once, and the data they adapt over reset as needed.

Comment: i found what caused it, in the function where i added a note i accidentally called adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged n times with n being the number of notes so the more notes there were the worse the performance, now it works great. i also changed the stuff you said and that did improve scrolling a bit. I cant get viewpool to work properly though, some notes just wont show up when i use it